# Issue with creating a group by SQL in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following django queryset:

```
     hero = DeedUser.objects\
    .select_related('user')\
    .values('user_id', 'user__display_name')\
    .annotate(total_deed=Count('user_id'))
```

and it returns the following:

```
SELECT "deeds_deeduser"."user_id", "users_user"."display_name", COUNT("deeds_deeduser"."user_id") AS "total_deed" FROM "deeds_deeduser" INNER JOIN "users_user" ON ( "deeds_deeduser"."user_id" = "users_user"."id" ) GROUP BY "deeds_deeduser"."user_id", "users_user"."display_name", "deeds_deeduser"."modified", "deeds_deeduser"."created" ORDER BY "deeds_deeduser"."modified" DESC, "deeds_deeduser"."created" DESC LIMIT 21
```

Why does it adds the fields **modified** and **created** to the **GROUP BY** since I've specified the value in select_related()

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
.order_by('total_deed')
```

and works now.